# Why are new built-in methods in javascript not supported by older browsers?

Tags: javascript

**Why are some built-in methods in JavaScript not supported by older browsers ?**

For example: The Array `fill()` method: (browser support: chrome[v.45], I.E[v.12.0], Opera[v.32.0], etc )

Out of curiosity I decided to *"reinvent the wheel"* and recreate the above method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>

Array.prototype.myFunction = function (staticValue, start, end) {
  for(var i = 0; i< this.length; i++) {

     if(i===start) {
         for(start= i; i<end+1; i++) {
             this[i] = staticValue;
         };
     };

     if(start == undefined && end == undefined) {
         this[i] = staticValue;
     };

  };

};

var testFruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", 456, 48999, "power"];

var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

testFruits.myFunction("Kiwi", 1, 3);

cars.myFunction("Voom!");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
testFruits + "<br />" + "<br />"  +cars;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Does this mean that by recreating some new but poorly supported built-in methods make your code completely supported by old browsers ?**

My theory is YES, considering that I only used regular functions and common techniques to come up with a solution.

Comment: Older browsers are old and no longer developed - many of these "new" methods have polyfills available (so you don't need to do the coding yourself)

Comment: Mozilla has an excellent reference  for JavaScript. It also has some polyfills that allow old browsers to act like newer browsers. For example, the array.fill() polyfill can be seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Polyfill

Comment: this is like asking why don't I know anything from my father's childhood?!

Comment: @BekimBacaj that's a zen meditation topic :)

Comment: The javascript engine is (always?) built into the browser, it's not a simple matter of inserting a new engine, so updates to the engine are typically released as new browser versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Older browsers are **old**. The people who implemented the older browsers don't go back and add new features.

If a JavaScript language feature was standardized in 2015, then a browser released in 2012 just doesn't have it because time travel is not common. It's not impossible that somebody might release an update for the old browser, but then it wouldn't be an old browser anymore.

Plain JavaScript implementations of new features are **sometimes** possible, and those are usually called "polyfills".  Many MDN pages include such code ([one example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill)). Some language features, however, involve new syntax, and that cannot be reproduced with simple JavaScript code of course.

Comment: Time travel +1 .  Not sure I'd want to anyway

Answer (score 1):

In practical sense and if you use compilation for your project you may consider to add at the top of your entry point

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support